# Metrics to Know the MYsql service running on ec2 is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have my Mysql service running on a Ec2 windows instances. Is there any Cloudwatch metrics to know the Mysql service is down or how can i check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a [custom metric](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/) based on the status of the mysql-server service.

Alternatively you could set alarms for outside normal bounds i.e. NetworkOut or CPU being low

Answer (score 0):

Install a cloudwatch logs agent as detailed here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html

Set up the agent to ship the mysql logs and the you can get graphs, set alarms and all the usual features of Cloudwatch

Alternatively, use a RDS instance and look at the RDS metrics see
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html

Comment: Thanks for you concern, will try this